# Pair to spend longest time in a single Sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, sql-date-functions

I have a long table with following columns:

Id(Serial), FirstName(varchar15), LastName(varchar15), StartDate(date), EndDate(date)

and the entries are like:

```
* 1, Amar, XoXo, 2009-07-01, 2014-05-23.
* 2, Madhujita, Mami, 2009-03-11, 2014-06-24.
* 3, Akbak Ladar, 2000-04-12, 2009-01-01.
* 4, Abhashuk, Genjin, 2005-06-03, 2005-09-09.
* 5, Sinra, Iao, 2014-01-01, 2014-04-06
```

and so on till 500 members.

How can I find out which two people have spent most time together and how many days?
Like for the given data Amar and Madhujita have spent the maximum time.
Can this be done in a single query?
Thank You.

Comment: Is there only one row per person?  Have you tried anything?  What database are you using?

Comment: Its' mysql and I am pretty bad in writing the queries. I have figured out the algorithm though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is one row per person, this is a question of getting the overlap between two spans.  The following query uses MySQL syntax to do this (MySQL supports `least()`, `greatest()` and `limit`).  This can be done in almost any database, but the exact syntax might vary:

```
select lt1.firstname, lt1.lastname, lt2.firstname, lt2.lastname,
       greatest(0, datediff(least(lt1.EndDate, lt2.EndDate), greatest(lt1.StartDate, lt2.StartDate))) as overlap
from LongTable lt1 cross join
     LongTable lt2
where lt1.id <> lt2.id
order by overlap desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f64ec1/4) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating it.

Comment: Still the same result with different value of overlap this time. I understand what you are trying to achieve here. I will refine the result and let you know if it works. Thanx anyways!

Comment: @Amar . . . I added the `where` clause and tested it on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Gordon, I followed your trail and landed up with a query myself with better understanding

```
select x.firstname as firstname1,x.lastname as surname1,y.firstname as firstname2,y.lastname as surname2
            from staff x inner join staff y on 
            x.startDate <= y.endDate and y.startDate <= x.endDate and x.firstname!=y.firstname and x.surname!=y.surname HAVING MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(x.startdate,x.endDate)-DATEDIFF(y.startDate,y.endDate)))
```